# CFG for string of length 3

Tags: context-free-grammar, computation-theory

I'm trying to create context free grammar for the following language:

> L={w∈{a,b}* | w is of the form a^nxb^n+2, where x is any string of
>   length 3 in {a,b}*}

(a is raised to the power of n, and b is raised to the power of n+2)

My solution this far is ( _ is epsilon):

S -> aSbb | T | _

T -> aT | bT | _

However this is not correct as it for example accepts string abbb. My problem is that I don't understand how to make the T part of the grammar, how can I limit the string to be size of 3? It would not make any sense to list all the strings of length 3 in {a,b}*, or is it the only way?

Also I'm not 100% confident if the aSbb is correct, because I think my solution is now a^nxb^2n, or am I wrong?

Comment: What about a rule `X -> a | b` and another rule `Y -> XXX`?

Comment: Ah, that's right, I think that will do it. Thank you! However I still think that my first rule S -> aSbb is not correct.

Comment: `a^nxb^n+2` is equivalent to `a^nxbbb^n` i.e `a^n(xbb)b^n`, which might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct CFG for the language is:

```
S -> aSb | T  
T -> UUUbb  
U -> a | b
```

Thanks everybody for help!